# Force a class to implement a specific constructor

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, constructor

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass<TSource>
{

     private Model _model;

     // ...

     public void SomeMethod()
     {
         // ...
         TSource instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSource), _model);
         // ...
     }
}
```

And then I have this class:

```
public class OtherClass
{
     public OtherClass(Model model)
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```

If I do the following, everything's fine:

```
SomeClass<OtherClass> someClass = // ....
someClass.SomeMethod();
```

But what if `OtherClass` has a parameterless constructor, or any constructor different than the stated?

Everything will compile just fine, but when creating the instance a runtime exception will be raised.

Is there a way to enforce the use of a certain constructor on every class that will be used as a generic argument to `SomeClass<>` ? (Like a generic constraint)

Comment: There's no generic constraint for doing this, the best you can do is pass a `Func<Model, TSource>` to create a new instance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can force a class to implement a constructor with arguments. But you can do a similar thing by forcing the class to implement an empty constructor, and a method that sets its model

Comment: @Doc How would you force a class to implement an empty constructor?

Comment: `public class SomeClass<TSource> where TSource : new()`